# Android downloading files - Issues with Stream that is not complete yet

Tags: android, android-download-manager

Im downloading files from a server, some big, some small.

```
protected Long doInBackground(Object... params) {
        Context context = (Context) params[0];
        String name = (String) params[1];
        String urlString = (String) params[2];
        File mediadir = context.getDir("tvr", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        try {
            URL url = new URL(urlString);
            URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
            connection.connect();
            int lenghtOfFile = connection.getContentLength();
            InputStream is = url.openStream();
            Log.d("DOWNLOAD NAME",name);
            File new_file = new File(mediadir, name);
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new_file.getPath());
            byte data[] = new byte[1024];
            int count = 0;
            long total = 0;
            int progress = 0;
            while ((count=is.read(data)) != -1){
                total += count;
                int progress_temp = (int)total*100/lenghtOfFile;
                if(progress_temp%10 == 0 && progress != progress_temp){
                    progress = progress_temp;
                }
                fos.write(data, 0, count);
            }
            is.close();
            fos.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Log.e("DOWNLOAD ERROR", e.toString());
        }
        return null;
    }
```

As I now understand it, Im downloading the file via a stream and streaming the data into a file. So in effect the file is created since the first byte of data.

Now, on the other end of things Im playing files from my internal directory by looking for files in a directory and then playing them:

```
mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
mediaPlayer.setDisplay(holder);
FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(path);
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(fileInputStream.getFD());
fileInputStream.close();
mediaPlayer.prepare();
mediaPlayer.start();
```

Now this issue is that the file will be played even though its not fully downloaded!

Is this true? If so, how must I check if the file is complete before trying to play it?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is a valid scenario, as in many cases your download speed will be slower than the reading and playing speed of the `MediaPlayer`.

Seeing as you're using an AsyncTask, you can fix this problem by calling the playing code in the `onPostExecute()` method, as that only runs after all work in the `doInBackground()` method has completed.

Comment: What about creating the streaming file in a temp directory, the after the stream is close, I move it to the real directory and then delete them temp directory file?

Comment: @Harry That would work too, but it would really be a waste of file I/O and disc operations.

Comment: Ok, Ill try what you suggest. Its gonna be allot of moving code around :-)

Comment: @Harry Just put the code in a method, and call the method from the onPostExecute(). That way if this doesn't work for you for some reason, you can just shift the method call instead of chunks of code